# Efeito em imagem css

Tags: css, css3

Como faco esse efeito como nessa imagem em css ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo usando a pseudo classe `::after`, assim vc não tem problema quando fizer o efeito no elemento em que o seu conteúdo está dentro. Para criar essa inclinação usei o `transform:skew` e usei flexbox para deixar tudo alinhado.

Veja o resultado no exemplo abaixo:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(http://unsplash.it/500/300);
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-right: 3rem;
}
.container::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transform: skew(-30deg) translateX(calc(50% + 3rem));
}
.cont {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="cont">
        <h1>Meu texto</h1>
        <p>texto texto</p>
        <button>BTN</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para criar esse efeito, basta utilizar `transform: skewX(-18deg);` no elemento que você deseja criar o efeito de inclinação.

**Exemplo:**

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0 }

.container {
  background:blue;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 149.8px;
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 314px;
}

/* Elemento inclinado */
.overlay {
  background: #00000050;
  height: 100%;
  width: 65%;
  margin-left: 46%;
  transform: skewX(-18deg);
  overflow:hidden;
}

h1, span {
  color:#FFF;
  display:block;
  margin: 30px;
  transform: skewX(18deg);
}
span {
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <span>Description</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sup>Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew</sup>

Você também pode usar um *background gradient* para fazer esse efeito. Basta adicionar `background: linear-gradient(107deg, transparent 20%, green 20%);` no elemento que você quer, por exemplo:

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0 }

.container {
  background:blue;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 149.8px;
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 314px;
}

/* Elemento inclinado */
.overlay {
  background: linear-gradient(107deg, transparent 20%, green 20%);
  float:right;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 60%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

h1, span {
  color:#FFF;
  display:block;
  margin: 30px;
}
span {
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <span>Description</span>
  </div>
</div>
```